# flink running error on mac standalone org.apache.flink.configuration.IllegalConfigurationException

Tags: macos, apache-flink, hadoop-yarn

I am new to `flink` and have install `yarn` and `flink` on my macbook with M1 pro chip.

when I tried to submit job using `bin/flink run -m yarn-cluster examples/streaming/SocketWindowWordCount.jar --port 8882` , it returned an error`Caused by: org.apache.flink.configuration.IllegalConfigurationException: The number of requested virtual cores for application master 1 exceeds the maximum number of virtual cores 0 available in the Yarn Cluster.`

Can anyone tell how to fix?

Really in a hurry. Many Thankssssss!!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Flink doesn't support ARM architectures. There are quite a number of open tickets involved with multiple problems to run Flink on Apple M1s. There is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-13448 which shows that some work has been done, but there still are issues open like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-25188, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-24932, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-22331, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-25505 and